# How to filter submodules in gradle to apply appropriate plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a multi-module project of which some are Java libraries and others Android libraries. I wanted to apply custom plugins for my sub projects (modules) depending on the project type, so I have done something like this (see below code snippet) in my project root's `build.gradle` file. This setup is working but I'm wondering if there is any other way of doing it. Gradle suggests [Filtering by properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#ssub:filtering_by_properties) but I get the error `Cannot add task 'integTest' as a task with that name already exists` if I try that. The `integTest` is a task I created in `customJavaBuild.gradle` and `customAndroidBuild.gradle` files. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
def javaLibraries = ["projA", "projB"]
def androidLibraries = ["projC"]

subprojects {
    if (javaLibraries.contains(it.name)) {
        apply from: '$rootDir/gradle/customJavaBuild.gradle'
    } else if (androidLibraries.contains(it.name)) {
        apply from: '$rootDir/gradle/customAndroidBuild.gradle'
    } else {
        //Apply custom plugin for some other project type.
    }
}
```

**Filtering by properties**

```
subprojects {
    project.ext {
        projectType = null
    }

    project.afterEvaluate {
        if (project.ext.projectType == 'jar') {
            apply from: '$rootDir/gradle/customJavaBuild.gradle'
        } else if (project.ext.projectType == 'aar') {
            apply from: '$rootDir/gradle/customAndroidBuild.gradle'
        } else {
            //Apply custom plugin for some other project type.
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this extra property `ext.projectType = 'jar'` in my sub-modules' (projA, projB, projC) `build.gradle` files.

Comment: The error you get indicates that you applied both `customJavaBuild.gradle` and `customAndroidBuild.gradle`  to a same sub-project, which is not allowed due to task `integTest` name collision. Can you share your solution based on "Filtering by properties" ? (at least the logic you implemented in the root project script, and how you implement the property in each sub-project to determine the project type)

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Thank you for the comment, I have added more code to the question that might help you.

Comment: I see the problem. please try the changes described in my answer, this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your `project.afterEvaluate` block you are applying your custom gradle script to the `root project` and not to the evaluated `sub project`, which causes the error with `integTest`task already defined.

You should rewrite your  `project.afterEvaluate` block with something similar to the following:

```
subprojects {
    project.ext {
        projectType = null
    }

    project.afterEvaluate {
        if (project.ext.projectType == 'jar') {
            // WARNING : use "project.apply ..." instead of "apply ..." here
            project.apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/customJavaBuild.gradle"
        } else if (project.ext.projectType == 'aar') {
            project.apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/customAndroidBuild.gradle"
        } else {
            // nothing
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Since it was under `project.afterEvaluate` closure, I didn't know I had to use `project.apply`. Thank you for the help.